# Dispatch is not a function when testing a redux action

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm learning to write tests for action creators with Jest and Enzyme. This is an action creator that I am using with React Native.

Please consider the code below:

```
import {
    FETCH_FAIL
} from './types';

export const fetchFail = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_FAIL,
        payload: "An error occurred. Try again later."
    });
};
```

I wrote the following test for this action creator:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

test('should fail fetch', async () => {
    const payload = {
        type: FETCH_FAIL,
        payload: "An error occurred. Try again later."
    }

    const store = mockStore({ data:[], isConnected: false });
    expect(store.dispatch(actions.fetchFail())).toEqual(payload);
})
```

My test fails with the following result:

> TypeError: dispatch is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to return the dispatched action from your `thunk`

```js
export const fetchFail = (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch({
        type: FETCH_FAIL,
        payload: "An error occurred. Try again later."
    });
};
```

And then don't call the `thunk` but pass the reference(remove the parentheses) because the `thunk` middleware is calling your action passing `dispatch` as the first argument when the action is a function

```js
test('should fail fetch', async () => {
    const payload = {
        type: FETCH_FAIL,
        payload: "An error occurred. Try again later."
    }

    const store = mockStore({ data:[], isConnected: false });
    // removed the parentheses around fetchFail()
    expect(store.dispatch(actions.fetchFail)).toEqual(payload);
})
```

Comment: It was not on the question, but I already had that piece of code in my tests and it's not working for some reason, @Asaf Aviv.

Comment: @RCohen can you include `noInternetConnection`?

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. The name of the function is `fetchFail()`. Could you check the code again, please?

Comment: @RCohen pass the thunk but don't invoke it, see updated answer and let me know if it's working

Comment: Okay, I removed the `()`. I get this: `Expected: {"payload": "An error occurred. Try again later.", "type": "FETCH_FAIL"}
    Received: undefined` @Asaf Aviv

Comment: @RCohen try to return the dispatched action from your thunk `return dispatch({})`

Comment: Omg, it works! The test passes now when I return `return dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAIL, payload: 'Try again'})` @Asaf Aviv

Comment: @RCohen Nice!, now it's time to refactor the other thunks you have :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Please edit your answer to suit this question ;) with the `return dispatch({})` @Asaf Aviv